# jQuery's val() not equal to attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I am developing a script that uses jQuery's val() and attr() but they seems not equal. They are both have the same text and length. When I compare both using IF statement they return false

```
var isSame = $(this).val() == $(this).attr("placeholder");
console.log('$(this).val() == $(this).attr("placeholder"): ' + isSame);
```

Looking on jQuery's API documentation on [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) and [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) they both return String that is so I tried adding .toString() on both values but they doesn't work either.

Here is the screenshot using IE developer tools, emulated IE7

[image: Here's the screenshot using IE]

Some of us are still using old browsers such as IE7 so I need to use and test it on IE7

Comment: `$(this).val()` is returning the current value of the input, meaning anything typed into it. `$(this).attr("placeholder")` returns the value of its placeholder parameter. Are you typing in "Employee No" before evaluation?

Comment: No! They both have the same text on window load

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/8w2xz1v8/show disregard the button and text input below. Press backspace or delete key using IE7